# Read TIF file error "Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data"

Tags: r, tiff, rgdal

I'm trying to read in a TIF file as follows:

```
d = readGDAL('F182013.v4c.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif')
Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : 
  Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: -180.004166667
```

The file is [night light data](http://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html) from US National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, so it should be a valid file.  Maybe the problem relates to a numerical floating point issue.

Grateful for any advice how to workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readGDAL` calls the error-checking function `validityMethod`, which checks that the longitude is within +/- 180 degrees for WGS84. Non-fatal errors and messages can be suppressed with:

```
d = readGDAL('F182013.v4c.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif', silent = TRUE)
```

so that the file can at least be read in as a SpatialGridDataFrame. The corresponding geographic range of the object is still beyond +/-180 deg, but the error may be within the tolerance you're willing to accept.

```
bbox(d)
         min       max
x -180.00417 180.00417
y  -65.00417  75.00417
```

Comment: Weirdly I get exactly the same error. Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm currently using Mac OS 10.10.4 with r (3.2.1) and rgdal (1.0-4)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is:

```
require(tiff)
r = raster(readTIFF(filepath, as.is = T))
extent(r) = extent(-180,180,-65,75)
crs(r) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```